# pdftk - WARNING: The creator of the input PDF: has set an owner password

Tags: pdftk

I am trying to merge multiple .pdf files into one.  I am getting an error stating there is a password on the files which prevents the consildation but there isn't a password request when I open the file and I have permissions set to read and write as well as execute as a file.

```
 pdftk *.pdf cat output BankPackage-2023
WARNING: The creator of the input PDF:
   OPEX Statement-4950 2022-10-20(1).pdf
   has set an owner password (which is not required to handle this PDF).
   You did not supply this password. Please respect any copyright.
```

Any solution?

Comment: are you running it in `do_ask` mode? or are you even supplying the "owner password"? If you read the message carefully, you'll see that a password isn't required to "handle this PDF" - clearly though, what you are doing DOES require an "owner password" - the "Please respect any copyright" message is a hint as to why you need such a password